# Why is rank($A-\lambda I)<n$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

In my lecture notes, it states $rank(A-\lambda I)<n$ for a quadratic matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and, thus, there *are* non-zero solutions. Why?

Comment: Because rank is equal to the number of linearly independent columns. Since there are less than $n$, by definition there is a non-trivial null space to $A-\lambda I$

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the case where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. In that case there exists an eigenvector $v \neq 0$ with $A v = \lambda v$. As such we get $(A- \lambda I) v = Av - \lambda v = \lambda v - \lambda v = 0$ which implies that $(A- \lambda I)$ can't have full rank and we get that $rank(A- \lambda I) < n$